# set ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion parameter when using New-ADUser

Tags: active-directory, powershell-3.0

Is it possible to set the `-ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion` parameter when using `New-ADUser` cmdlet or do I have to use `Set-ADObject` after?

Can I set this as the default for "Users"?

This a list of parameters available when doing man New-ADUser

```
New-ADUser
[-Name] <string>
[-WhatIf] [-Confirm]
[-AccountExpirationDate <datetime>]
[-AccountNotDelegated <bool>]
[-AccountPassword <securestring>]
[-AllowReversiblePasswordEncryption <bool>]
[-AuthType <ADAuthType> {Negotiate | Basic}]
[-CannotChangePassword <bool>]
[-Certificates <X509Certificate[]>]
[-ChangePasswordAtLogon <bool>]
[-City <string>]
[-Company <string>]
[-CompoundIdentitySupported <bool>]
[-Country <string>]
[-Credential <pscredential>]
[-Department <string>]
[-Description <string>]
[-DisplayName <string>]
[-Division <string>]
[-EmailAddress <string>]
[-EmployeeID <string>]
[-EmployeeNumber <string>]
[-Enabled <bool>]
[-Fax <string>]
[-GivenName <string>]
[-HomeDirectory <string>]
[-HomeDrive <string>]
[-HomePage <string>]
[-HomePhone <string>]
[-Initials <string>]
[-Instance <ADUser>]
[-KerberosEncryptionType <ADKerberosEncryptionType> {None | DES | RC4 | AES128 | AES256}]
[-LogonWorkstations <string>]
[-Manager <ADUser>]
[-MobilePhone <string>]
[-Office <string>]
[-OfficePhone <string>]
[-Organization <string>]
[-OtherAttributes <hashtable>]
[-OtherName <string>]
[-PassThru]
[-PasswordNeverExpires <bool>]
[-PasswordNotRequired <bool>]
[-Path <string>]
[-POBox <string>]
[-PostalCode <string>]
[-PrincipalsAllowedToDelegateToAccount <ADPrincipal[]>]
[-ProfilePath <string>]
[-SamAccountName <string>]
[-ScriptPath <string>]
[-Server <string>]
[-ServicePrincipalNames <string[]>]
[-SmartcardLogonRequired <bool>]
[-State <string>]
[-StreetAddress <string>]
[-Surname <string>]
[-Title <string>]
[-TrustedForDelegation <bool>]
[-Type <string>]
[-UserPrincipalName <string>]
[<CommonParameters>]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to specify that parameter when using `New-ADUser`, however you can use `-ProtectedFromAccidentalDeltion $true` when creating an account using the `New-ADObject` commandlet. See the example from TechNet below:

```
New-ADObject -name SaraDavisContact -type contact -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $true -OtherAttributes @{'msDS-SourceObjectDN'="CN=FabrikamContacts,DC=CONTOSO,DC=COM"}
```

In the example above, a contact is being created, but you could simply change the logic to achieve your desired results.

For more information, see this article:

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617260.aspx

**NOTE: Be mindful that the New-ADObject command is a much more powerful commandlet.**

Answer (score 0):

**To read it**

```
$adProps = Get-ADUser -Identity [SamAccountName] -Server [domain controller or domain] -Properties * ;
$adPropsDC.ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion;
False
```

**To set it**

```
Set-ADObject -Identity $adProps.DistinguishedName -Server [domain controller or domain] -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion:$true ;
```

**To verify it**

```
$adProps = Get-ADUser -Identity [SamAccountName] -Server [domain controller or domain] -Properties * ;
$adPropsDC.ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion;
True
```